# Regular Expression explanation: (?>[^<>]+)

Tags: php, regex, pcre

How should this, `/(?>[^<>]+)/`, be interpreted please? (PHP RegExp Engine)

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid regex.

Comment: The `?` IS valid there. It's an atomic group.

Comment: +1 Interesting, never heard that. My regex tester threw an error.

Comment: What I don't get is what use does it have in a regex like `/(?>[^<>]+)/`??

Comment: `(?>[^<>]+)` is exactly the same as `[^<>]++`.

Comment: It's not the same because it's not uselessly reccursive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?>        # I had to look this up, but apparently this syntax prevents the regex
           # parser from backtracking into whatever is matched in this group if 
           # the rest of the  pattern fails
   [^<>]+  # match ANY character except '<' or '>', 1 or more times. 
         ) # close non-backtrackable group.
```

For anyone interested in the once-only pattern, check out the section `Once-only subpatterns` in http://www.regextester.com/pregsyntax.html

Comment: If you’re using Perl regular expressions, you should always consult [the appropriate documentation.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: @tchrist He's asking about PHP though

Comment: And where do you think the *preg_* functions get their name?

Comment: He's talking about PCRE, so the most accurate documentation would be at http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt

Comment: Ok fair enough, but what about the differences in the PHP implementation mentioned in the site I used?

Comment: Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions are not entirely compatible with perl regular expressions.  Also, there are differences across implementations.  Best documentation is at http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php

Comment: And for `(?>...)` specifically: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.onlyonce.php